# How to update a var inside if-statement in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, if-statement, scope, var

I have a tracking variable that is supposed to denote whether we've arrived at a certain branch in a nested if-else statement. Here's a simplified example

```
var varChanged = false
if(true) {
  var varChanged = true
}

varChanged //still returns false
```

I would like to update the value of `varChanged` within the if statement. How should I go about doing this? I can't use the if statement as an expression like `var varChanged = if(..)..` because I'm using it as an expression for another val and `varChanged` is just a tracking variable that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the inner `var` keyword

```scala
var varChanged = false
if(true) {
  varChanged = true
}
```

You were shadowing the outer `varChanged` by declaring it again in the inner scope.

You should really avoid using `var`s as much as possible.

Comment: thanks! Is there another way I can do this while avoiding `var`? what's the reason for avoiding `var` as much as possible?

Comment: I mean your case is too trivial: `val varChanged = true`. Just force yourself to use `val`. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-idiom-immutable-code-functional-programming-immutability/ these are some resons but you can read more about immutability elsewhere as well.

Comment: but in my case `val varChanged = true` wouldn't work because I can't update a `val`. Is another way to do this aside from using `var`? Situation like this or having to set up a counter of some sort for a for-loop happens often in my code

Comment: I don't know what your whole code looks like..... you should not use for loops either....